# serie para drilldown usando array y json_encode

Tags: php, json, mysqli, highcharts

Estoy realizando un gráfico de tipo drilldown https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown el cual de momento a modo de prueba pretendo mostrar años(eje x) y un numerador (eje y) traídos desde mi base de datos, de momento estoy un poco perdido pues la gráfica que estoy usando trabaja con unas peculiaridades que me han constado dominar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Practica</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="js/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
 <script src="js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
 <script src="js/exporting.js"></script>
 <script src="js/export-data.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/data.js"></script>
 <script src="js/drilldown.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Practica. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },
    <?php  
        include 'conexion/conexion.php';
        $query = "
            SELECT 
            r.var_numerador_mujeres_casadas,
            a.mujeres_anio_casadas 
            FROM resumen_mujeres_casadas r 
            INNER JOIN mujeres_anios_casadas a ON r.id_mujeres_anios_casadas = a.id_mujeres_anios_casadas
        ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $query);
        if ($result) 
        {
            $arrayData['data'] = array();

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
            {
                array_push($arrayData['data'], array(
                    'name:'         => $row['mujeres_anio_casadas'],
                    'y:'            => (int)$row['var_numerador_mujeres_casadas'],
                    'drilldown:'    => $row['mujeres_anio_casadas']
                ));        
            }
        }//FIN DEL IF RESULT
    ?>
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        data: [<?php echo $var = json_encode($arrayData); ?>]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            data: [
                [
                    'v11.0',
                    24.13
                ],
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    17.2
                ],
                [
                    'v9.0',
                    8.11
                ],
                [
                    'v10.0',
                    5.33
                ],
                [
                    'v6.0',
                    1.06
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.5
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            id: 'Chrome',
            data: [
                [
                    'v40.0',
                    5
                ],
                [
                    'v41.0',
                    4.32
                ],
                [
                    'v42.0',
                    3.68
                ],
                [
                    'v39.0',
                    2.96
                ],
                [
                    'v36.0',
                    2.53
                ],
                [
                    'v43.0',
                    1.45
                ],
                [
                    'v31.0',
                    1.24
                ],
                [
                    'v35.0',
                    0.85
                ],
                [
                    'v38.0',
                    0.6
                ],
                [
                    'v32.0',
                    0.55
                ],
                [
                    'v37.0',
                    0.38
                ],
                [
                    'v33.0',
                    0.19
                ],
                [
                    'v34.0',
                    0.14
                ],
                [
                    'v30.0',
                    0.14
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            id: 'Firefox',
            data: [
                [
                    'v35',
                    2.76
                ],
                [
                    'v36',
                    2.32
                ],
                [
                    'v37',
                    2.31
                ],
                [
                    'v34',
                    1.27
                ],
                [
                    'v38',
                    1.02
                ],
                [
                    'v31',
                    0.33
                ],
                [
                    'v33',
                    0.22
                ],
                [
                    'v32',
                    0.15
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            id: 'Safari',
            data: [
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    2.56
                ],
                [
                    'v7.1',
                    0.77
                ],
                [
                    'v5.1',
                    0.42
                ],
                [
                    'v5.0',
                    0.3
                ],
                [
                    'v6.1',
                    0.29
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.26
                ],
                [
                    'v6.2',
                    0.17
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            id: 'Opera',
            data: [
                [
                    'v12.x',
                    0.34
                ],
                [
                    'v28',
                    0.24
                ],
                [
                    'v27',
                    0.17
                ],
                [
                    'v29',
                    0.16
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
</script>
```

Ahí un detalle no he tocado la parte del según nivel del drilldown porque aun no paso del primero nivel.

Lo siguiente es el código PHP que hace la consulta es el siguiente.

```html
    <?php  
        include 'conexion/conexion.php';
        $query = "
            SELECT 
            r.var_numerador_mujeres_casadas,
            a.mujeres_anio_casadas 
            FROM resumen_mujeres_casadas r 
            INNER JOIN mujeres_anios_casadas a ON r.id_mujeres_anios_casadas = a.id_mujeres_anios_casadas
        ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $query);
        if ($result) 
        {
            $arrayData['data'] = array();

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
            {
                array_push($arrayData['data'], array(
                    'name:'         => $row['mujeres_anio_casadas'],
                    'y:'            => (int)$row['var_numerador_mujeres_casadas'],
                    'drilldown:'    => $row['mujeres_anio_casadas']
                ));        
            }
        }//FIN DEL IF RESULT
    ?>
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        data: [<?php echo $var = json_encode($arrayData); ?>]
    }],
```

a mi parecer es la parte que no he podido hacer funcionar aunque con el json_encode creo tener un avance por el tipo de respuesta que reviso en la consola del navegador. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver es lo mas parecido al formato de la serie para el gráfico, si me pudieran ayudar les agradecería mucho o si me pueden dar algún apoyo con una forma diferente de trabajar con el drilldown
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
$arrayData= array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
    array_push($arrayData, array(
          "name"   => $row['mujeres_anio_casadas'],
          "y"      => (int)$row['var_numerador_mujeres_casadas'],
          "drilldown"    => $row['mujeres_anio_casadas']
      ));        
}
```

Logre darme una solución, hoy por la mañana, pero entre en la segunda complicación y es sobre el drilldown de segundo nivel con el cual siempre me da error en la estructura de la serie. Sigo a la espera.

Comment: buen dia Julio, con una consulta pudiste resolver el segundo nivel del drilldown?
si es asi podrias ayudarme a saber de que formalo lo hiciste.
gracias